# My desktop keeps rebooting after startup

Tags: windows-7

After my desktop slipped out of my hands and fell a few centimeters to the floor (it didn't fall over or anything, but it was still quite a shock), it doesn't start up as it should.

When I try to start it up, it seems as usual, but after 10-15 seconds it instantly shuts off. A few seconds after that it will automatically start up again, only to shut off again, and so on.

During this process the monitor doesn't turn on and stays black.

I've opened it up and re-plugged some of the cables, but most of them seem to be stuck in place. I've also removed the RAM but that doesn't work either.

Unfortunately, this is as far as my computer knowledge goes and I don't know how to solve the problem. I've tried looking for solutions but I couldn't find any and I'm hoping someone here can offer a solution.

Comment: Probably a hardware failure.  Have you tried keeping the PC powered on after disconnecting hard disk? May be you may try a live disc of any Linux distro (Ubuntu, Fedora etc)

Comment: If you have a mechanical HDD try using "chkdsk /f" (if you can do that; I assume the BIOS or UEFI still works) while booting from your PC from Windows DVD (maybe the filesystem just gone wrong or you have made a few bad sectors on impact). If you have SSD then this might be what Nikhil_CV says.

Comment: I just tried starting the pc without the hard disk connected but it shuts down after ten seconds like before. I also tried using the command as you suggested but the pc shuts down before i can do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

The startup/shutoff cycling might be overheating due to an unplugged or stuck fan, particularly the one on the CPU heatsink. See if the fan spins easily when the PC is off, and see if it spins up when turned on.

Comment: The fans can spin easily and they work fine when I start up the pc, until it shuts down of coure.